# How to unittest a global error handler?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, error-handling

I have the following function and I need to know how to write a UnitTest for it. (the HandleError function)

```
    public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        this.Startup += App_Startup;
        Dispatcher.UnhandledException += HandleError;
    }
     private void HandleError(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        string exception = e.Exception.Message;
        MessageBox.Show(exception + "\"", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

I am fairly new to UnitTest so i might not know as much.

Comment: That method is tightly coupled to UI implementation concerns which makes it difficult to test in isolation. abstract out the UI concerns which would allow for mocks to be substituted in, making the code more flexible for testing in isolation.

Comment: On what platform is that code executing. winform? wpf?.....?

Comment: The platform used is wpf

Comment: Is DI (Dependency Inversion) being used?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means but i added some code which might help

Comment: First you need to read up and understand what is unit testing and the problem it is meant to solve. next you need to understand how to write code in a way that makes it testable.

Comment: What edition of Visual studio are you using?

Comment: What is the logic you want to test in "App"?

Answer (score 2):

So, there are good news and there are bad news.
The good news - yes, you can unit test it, even in the free Visual Studio.
The bad news - since you're using a static `MessageBox.Show` your unit test actually results in actual box showing.

Unit test code:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void App_Handles_Exceptions()
    {
      var app = new App();
      var dapp = (DispatcherObject)app;
      var mi = typeof(Dispatcher).GetMethod("CatchException", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
      var handled = (bool)mi.Invoke(dapp.Dispatcher, new object[] { new Exception("a") });

      Assert.IsTrue(handled);
    }
```

Now if you do happen to have an Enterprise edition of Visual Studio (sadly, even with 2017 it's required), you can use the Microsoft Fakes feature and then the test is completely isolated with no side effects:

```
[TestMethod]
public void App_Handles_Exceptions_WithFakes()
{
  using (ShimsContext.Create())
  {
    string usedMessage = null;
    string usedError = null;
    System.Windows.Fakes.ShimMessageBox.ShowStringStringMessageBoxButtonMessageBoxImage = (s, s1, arg3, arg4) =>
      {
        usedMessage = s;
        usedError = s1;
        return MessageBoxResult.OK;
      };

    var app = new App();
    var dapp = (DispatcherObject)app;
    var mi = typeof(Dispatcher).GetMethod("CatchException", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    var handled = (bool)mi.Invoke(dapp.Dispatcher, new object[] { new Exception("a") });

    Assert.IsTrue(handled);
    Assert.AreEqual("a\"", usedMessage);
    Assert.AreEqual("Error", usedError);
  }
}
```

This is the intro to Microsoft Fakes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx